# JSON Output File Format

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I am using Canvasjs Charts to do my graphing from PHP / MySQL. Everything works as expected except for the creating of my JSON file.

Canvasjs requires the JSON file to look as follow:

```
callback({  
   "dps":
[{"division":"Xaxis VALUE","units":Yaxis VALUE}]
})
```

However, when creating my JSON file it is

```
[{"division":"Xaxis VALUE","units":Yaxis VALUE}]
```

All I want to know is how do I add the opening tag and closing tag in the sjon file from my script.

Here is the last part of my code that creates the JSON file:

```
$output_data= array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output_data[] = array(
                                'division' => $row["division"],     
                                'units' => $row["units"]

                                );
    }

return json_encode($output_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);    
echo json_encode($output_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);   
}




$file_name = 'myresult2'.'.json';

if(file_put_contents($file_name, get_data()))
{
    echo $file_name. 'file created';
}
else
{
  echo 'Error';  
}

?>
```

Additional Data:
This is the code that generates the graph.

```
<script>

var chart = null;
var dataPoints = [];

window.onload = function() {



chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light",
    title: {
        text: "Graph Header"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "% Verified",
        titleFontSize: 12,
        labelFontSize: 12,
        valueFormatString: "#.##%"      

    },
    axisX: {
        title: "Division",
        titleFontSize: 12,
        labelFontSize: 12
    },    
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        yValueFormatString: "#.##%",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
});


$.getJSON("myresult.json?callback=?", callback);    

}

function callback(data) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < data.dps.length; i++) {
        dataPoints.push({
            label: data.dps[i].division,
            y: data.dps[i].units
        });
    }
    chart.render(); 
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
// change this
$output_data[] = array(

// to this
$output_data['dps'][] = array(
```

Comment: This will overwrite the `$output_data['dps']` each time in the while loop

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo. Copy & paste is not always your friend.

Comment: The update overwrites all the data, so the JSON file is empty using the updated code.

Comment: @LeonClaassen, `$output_data['dps'][]` appends elements to the end of the array. It should not be overwriting anything. The only difference between your original code and mine code is adding the desired `['dps']` element to the beginning of the array you want to output as json

Comment: My bad... It's working now. Thanks. I made a typo. To add the Callback ( ) as well, do I just extend on the update?

Comment: @LeonClaassen, a typo? I did the same thing ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Mr Glass. Only thing that still needs to be added to the file is Callback ( at the begining and then a closing )

Comment: @LeonClaassen, getting the json to `callback()` depends on how you are using the json. Is this an AJAX call? Is it loading the json into the page before the page is rendered?

Comment: I've added some additional code. The graphs are being created with javascript.

I just don't understand why the json file needs to follow this format:
callback({ 
"dps":
[{"division":"Xaxis VALUE","units":Yaxis VALUE}]    
})

Comment: You'll need to modify your `callback()` function to parse the json data it receives. Something like `data = JSON.parse(data);` as the first line of the function should do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is enclose you created array in a new array with a key named `dps`.

So after your `while` loop you should do something like this

`$json_data['dps']=$output_data;`

`return json_encode($json_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: Thanks @Dimitris, Tried this one, but is does not seem to add the desired tags at the opening and end. I need the entire string of callback({  
   "dps": & })